# will_paginate - highly specific ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I have a `priority` field with four options: "Urgent", "High", "Normal", and "Low".

I have this field displayed in a table of records, and I am using will_paginate's ordering as follows:

```
@projects = @company.projects.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)

private
def sort_column
  ['priority', 'name'].include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "priority"
end
```

A typical ordering as above will give me:

1. High
2. Low
3. Normal
4. Urgent

This order is wrong. How can I get this column to order specifically to Urgent, High, Normal, Low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if Rails has an easier way to do this, but the way I typically see it done is to have a separate table holding your priorities along with an order field that's just an integer.  Then you just join to that table and order by the integer field.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you suggest to take a look at this [screencast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch)

It does the sort data columns very easy to implement.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your DB is sorting the priority in lexicographic order. The easiest solution is to map those string priorities to integer priorities and sort on that - as @jdc suggested.

I'd probably tend to stay away from storing the priorities in a separate table just so you dont have to do a join, and just store the numerical priority in a new column.

But the idea is the same.